# DatePicker in bootstrap

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add time field using datetimepicker. I am getting widget, but if I select AM and leave that field comeback to same field  then it goes to PM. Could anyone suggest on it.

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   format: 'LT',
   keepOpen: false,
   locale:'en'
});
```

Comment: Please post the full code, and what datetimepicker are you using?

Comment: I am using bootstrap datepicker. My form having below filed and js having that script.
"''<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" value="" id="datetimepicker" name="time" autocomplete="off">"'

Js:
""'$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   format: 'LT',
   keepOpen: false,
   locale:'en'
}); ""'

Comment: Can you post a link to the full code though, perhaps github or codesandbox?